# Best way to create Elements dynamically in QML based on C++ QMap

Tags: c++, qt, qml

This seemed like a simple task at first, but honestly I am struggling. I have a Map of profiles I load at startup, and profiles can be added and deleted at runtime. Those profiles need to be listed as RadioButtons or some other element for selection/editing in my UI.

I've tried using createQMLObject() while looping trough a QVariantMap getter:

**profile.h**

```
    #ifndef PROFILE_H
    #define PROFILE_H
    
    #include <QObject>
    
    class Profile final :  public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Profile(QObject *parent = nullptr);
        ~Profile(){}
        Profile(QString profileName = "default", QObject *parent = nullptr);
        
        QString getProfileName() const;
        void setProfileName(const QString &value);
    private:
        QString profileName;
    };
    
    #endif // PROFILE_H
```

**profile.cpp**

```
#include "profile.h"

Profile::Profile(QString profileName, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), profileName{ profileName }{}

QString Profile::getProfileName() const
{
    return profileName;
}

void Profile::setProfileName(const QString &value)
{
    profileName = value;
}
```

**controller.h**

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include "profile.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlEngine>

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Controller(){}

    static QObject* controllerSingletonProvider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine);
    static Controller* instance();

    Q_INVOKABLE void addProfile(QString profileName);

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariantList getLoadedProfiles(){
        QVariantList rval;
        foreach (QString key, loadedProfiles.keys()) {
            rval.append(QVariant::fromValue<Profile*>(loadedProfiles[key].get()));
        }
        return rval;
    };

private:
    QMap<QString, std::shared_ptr<Profile>> loadedProfiles;

signals:

};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

**controller.cpp**

```
#include "controller.h"

Controller::Controller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent){}

void Controller::addProfile(QString profileName)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Profile> profile{std::make_shared<Profile>(profileName)};
    loadedProfiles[profile->getProfileName()] = profile;
}

QObject* Controller::controllerSingletonProvider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

    return Controller::instance();
}

Controller* Controller::instance(){
    static Controller* controller = new Controller();
    return controller;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
    #include <QGuiApplication>
    #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
    #include <controller.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    
        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    
        qmlRegisterSingletonType<Controller>("com.controller", 1, 0, "Controller", Controller::controllerSingletonProvider);
        Controller::instance()->addProfile("Profile1");
    
        const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
        QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                         &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
        engine.load(url);
    
        return app.exec();
    }
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import com.controller 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        id: radioButtonColumn

        Component.onCompleted: {
            for(var profile in Controller.getLoadedProfiles()){
                var obj = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.12; RadioButton { id: '+ profile.getProfileName() +';
                                     text: '+ profile.getProfileName() +'; }', radioButtonColumn, "dynamicSnippet1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using a signal sent from my Controller Singleton using Connections, but the parameter of the signal does not arrive. I can however call my Controllers c++ functions from qml. I'll only post the changes to the previous code sample:

**main.qml changes:**

```
Connections {
    target: Controller
    onProfileAdded: {
        var obj = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.12; RadioButton { id: '+ profileName +';
                             text: '+ profileName +'; }', radioButtonColumn, "dynamicSnippet1");
        console.log("Value changed")
    }
}
```

**controller.h changes:**

```
    signals:
        void profileAdded(QString &profileName);
    };
```

**controller.cpp changes:**

```
void Controller::addProfile(QString profileName)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Profile> profile{std::make_shared<Profile>(profileName)};
    loadedProfiles[profile->getProfileName()] = profile;
    emit profileAdded(profileName);
}
```

**main.cpp changes:**

```
    engine.load(url);

    Controller::instance()->addProfile("Profile2");

    return app.exec();
```

*Edit: Curious, that I had to change my onProfileAdded in controller.h to profileAdded for the signal to work. However, I still do not receive the parameter profileName in my qml.*

I would like to ask what is the best way to handle a requirement like this. Maybe there is another, simpler way?

Im new to both c++ and QT, so please bear with my perhaps trivial question, but my research didnt yield me anything, that I could understand at least.

Comment: _I've tried using createQMLObject()_ ... _I've tried using a signal_ ...  ok, but why don't you provide your code?  please provide [mcve] and so we can check it

Comment: My first question is the best practice way to do it. I can think of 4 ways that could maybe work, access my c++ map in qml, access qml objects in c++, signal/slot, or a QVariantMap property that reacts to changes.

I'd like to hone in on the best way to do it, before posting 4 reproducable examples.

Comment: Why not share all 4 tried possibilities if you've tried/thought of them anyway? These could help other programmers that might need to consider which of the alternatives is best for their projects. These could help us resolve errors, or make it easier to explain the very general problem. _To me_, it's too vague to help you at this moment.

Comment: Alright, I started adding code samples for the ones I mentioned in my post and I will start adding the other variants as soon as I (re-)code them.

Comment: I think using your C++ QMap as a model for a Repeater or ListView would be the approach I would take.